# Javascript will not work when using shortcodes in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I made a plugin which uses Java-script for Google maps. The plugin is fully functional on the admin pages. When I use a short-code to display the plugin on a regular page for the front end user's, the JavaScript is not working?

Everything else works, the select boxes, and my table of dynamically displayed content from the database, but the java Script I use for the maps is not working.

I am not using jquery or any $'s so I have no idea why this is breaking. Thanks!

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
                                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                                //function for retrieving coordinates
                                function getCoordinates (address, callback){
                                    var coordinates;
                                    geocoder.geocode({address:address},    function (results, status){
                                        coords_obj=   results[0].geometry.location;
                                        coordinates =   [coords_obj.k,coords_obj.D];
                                        callback(coordinates);
                                    })
                                }


                                var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                                    new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                                    new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
                                var center = null;
                                var map = null;
                                var currentPopup;
                                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                                function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                                    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                                    bounds.extend(pt);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: pt,
                                        icon: icon,
                                        map: map
                                    });
                                    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                        content: info,
                                        maxWidth: 500

                                    });
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                                        if (currentPopup != null) {
                                            currentPopup.close();
                                            currentPopup = null;
                                        }
                                        popup.open(map, marker);
                                        currentPopup = popup;
                                    });
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                                        map.panTo(center);
                                        currentPopup = null;
                                    });
                                }
                                function initMap() {
                                    //retrives coordinates from address - not the best practice but it works for now
                                    getCoordinates('<?php echo $paddress ?>', function(coords){

                                        // centers map based on coordinates of the address
                                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]),
                                            zoom: 9,
                                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                            mapTypeControl: false,
                                            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                                            },
                                            navigationControl: true,
                                            navigationControlOptions: {
                                                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                                            }
                                        });
                                        // paitents Address marker
                                        var pmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]), title:"Paitents Address!"});
                                        pmarker.setMap(map);
                                        // adds markers on map from database based on specialist and insurance by lat and long
                                        <?php
                                        $query = "SELECT * FROM $specialist WHERE $insurance=1 AND is_active=1";
                                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                                        while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                        $name=$row['provider'];
                                        $lat=$row['lat'];
                                        $lon=$row['lon'];
                                        $address=$row['address'];
                                        $phone = $row['phone'];
                                        $fax = $row['fax'];
                                        echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<p><b>$name</b><br/>$address<br/>Phone:$phone<br/>Fax:$fax<br/></p>');\n");
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        center = bounds.getCenter();

                                    })
                                }
                                //]]>
                            </script>
```

Comment: It is hard to find the problem of a code and give a solution, one can not take a look at!

Comment: When I built this plugin, I put all my javaScript in an included php file along with my html markup. Since this is a plugin do I still have to make a function what en queues and registers scripts on my main plugin php file like in a word press theme for the Javascript to work?

Comment: Yes, you are better off keeping the Javascript in separate files and using wp_enqueue_script in your plugin main file.